# What is this data referencing anti-pattern called?

Tags: database, reference, anti-patterns

I have a question related to a kind of duplication I see in databases from time to time. To ask this question, I need to set the stage a bit:

Let's say I have a database of TV shows. Its primary table `Content` stores information at various levels of granularity (`Show -> Season -> Episode`), using a parent column to denote hierarchy:

```
+----+---------------------------+-------------+----------+
| ID |        ContentName        | ContentType | ParentId |
+----+---------------------------+-------------+----------+
|  1 | Friends                   | Show        | [null]   |
|  2 | Season 1                  | Season      | 1        |
|  3 | The Pilot                 | Episode     | 2        |
|  4 | The One with the Sonogram | Episode     | 2        |
+----+---------------------------+-------------+----------+
```

Maybe this isn't ideal, but let's say it's good enough to work with and we're not looking to change it.

Now let's say we need to build a table that defines air dates. We can set these at any level, and they must apply down the hierarchy (e.g., if set at the Season level, it applies to all episodes within that season; if set at the Show level, it applies to all seasons and episodes).

So the original air dates might look like this:

```
+-------+-----------+------------+
| airId | ContentId |  AirDate   |
+-------+-----------+------------+
|    71 |         3 | 1994-09-22 |
|    72 |         4 | 1994-09-29 |
+-------+-----------+------------+
```

Whereas the air date for a streaming service might look like:

```
+-------+-----------+------------+
| airId | ContentId |  AirDate   |
+-------+-----------+------------+
|    91 |         1 | 2015-01-01 |
+-------+-----------+------------+
```

Cool. Everything's fine so far; we're adhering to 4NF (I think!) and we can proceed to our business logic.

Now we get to my question. If we implement our business logic in such a way that disregards the referential hierarchy, and instead *duplicates* the air dates down the hierarchy, what is this anti-pattern called? e.g., Let's say I set an air date at the Show level like above, but the business logic finds all child elements and creates an entry for each one, resulting in:

```
+-------+-----------+------------+
| airId | ContentId |  AirDate   |
+-------+-----------+------------+
|    91 |         1 | 2015-01-01 |
|    92 |         2 | 2015-01-01 |
|    93 |         3 | 2015-01-01 |
|    94 |         4 | 2015-01-01 |
+-------+-----------+------------+
```

There are some pretty clear problems with this, but please note that my question is not how to *fix* this. Just, is there a specific term for it? I want to call it something like, "disregarding data relationship" or, "ignoring referential context". Maybe it's not strictly a *database* anti-pattern, since in my example there's an external actor inserting the excess rows.

Comment: Why keeping dates for every episode is an anti pattern? Maybe the anti pattern is to have another table just for the air dates and not including it in the first table though.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a database design issue, since I think it's OK. It's more like a query issue where the query is "cascading down" from the top, [maybe wrongly] superseding the values of branches and leaves.

Comment: I see it as an anti-pattern because it involves more records than it *needs* to. In the last scenario, if I want to make a change at the Show level, my business logic needs to go find all the related records and update them, whereas that's unnecessary. (Or even worse, if I make a change at the Show level, but my business logic *doesn't* update everything else for whatever reason, I end up in a broken state.)

Comment: This is a good question. I would say that the anti-pattern here is column `ContentType `. Why? Because `The Pilot` should be in an `Episode` table, `Season 1` should be in a `Season` table. The name of this anti-pattern is `Data redundancy`.  Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_redundancy#In_database_systems